# Perl threading of object method

Tags: multithreading, perl, oop

Perl rookie here, so please be gentle :)

I've written following code to keep track of my dogs when I'm hunting (not really). Every time a dog finds a duck, it signals the main thread, which then collects information from each of the dogs in the pack.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

use threads;

{
    package Dog;

    sub new {
        my ($class, $name, $dt) = @_;
        my $self = {
            dt => $dt,      # will find a duck every $dt seconds
            name => $name,
            ducksfound => 0
        };
        bless $self, $class;
    }

    sub hunt {
        #
        # the "thread" method -- the dog will hang around for $dt seconds,
        # then alert the main thread by sending SIGUSR1
        #
        my $self = shift;
        while (1) {
            sleep $self->{dt};
            $self->{ducksfound} += 1;
            kill USR1 => $$;
        }
    }

    sub bark {
        my $self = shift;
        sprintf "%s: found %d ducks!", ($self->{name}, $self->{ducksfound});
    }

    1;
}

my @dogs;

$SIG{USR1} = sub {
    say join ", ", map { $_->bark } @dogs;
};


push @dogs, Dog->new("Labrador", 1);
push @dogs, Dog->new("Retriever", 2);
push @dogs, Dog->new("Shepherd", 3);

threads->create( sub { $_->hunt } ) for @dogs;
$_->join for threads->list;
```

**Expected output of the above code would be something like:**

> Labrador: found 1 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 2 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 3 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 3 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 4 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 5 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 6 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 6 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 6 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 1 ducks!

**Instead, what I get is the following:**

> Labrador: found 1 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 2 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 3 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 0 ducks!, Retriever: found 1 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 4 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 5 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 0 ducks!, Retriever: found 2 ducks!, Shepherd: found 0 ducks!
>
> Labrador: found 0 ducks!, Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 1 ducks!

Notice how every dog's duck count resets to zero whan another dog is speaking.

Any insights as to which particular footnote I must have glossed over while reading the Llama?

Comment: This is a pretty great question for a Perl rookie. :)

Comment: signals and threads don't mix well.  you can't signal a particular thread afaik.  update: seems the threads doc disagrees, but shows using `$thr->kill`, not plain kill

Comment: @JonahBishop -- thanks, I guess :) Got impatient halfway through the Alpaca, started scratching one of my proverbial itches... guess this is what I get for coding out of turn :)

Comment: @ysth -- but $thr->kill is for signaling a particular thread, not (as I want) for a thread to signal the mothership; right?

Comment: What OS are you running this in? I get a number of errors using an ActivePerl installation on Windows 7 x64...

Comment: @JonahBishop -- Linux 3.7.7 x64, Perl 5.16. What sort of errors?

Comment: I get a `No such signal: SIGUSR1` error, then every thread terminates abnormally due to the signal not being present. Very strange...

Comment: K-spacer: you can't signal the mothership, you can only signal a thread.

Comment: BTW, threads in perl are not the lightweight things that other languages have; there are almost no problems where threads are the right solution in perl.

Comment: I've tried wrapping your code in a main thread and doing ->kill on that (and sharing the Dogs which you aren't yet doing), but no luck so far; did get a segfault though :)   You probably want to use threads::shared cond_wait/cond_signal anyway.

Comment: @ysth What I need is a mothership controlling a number of autonomous sub-units. These need to run in the background, doing their thing, alerting the mothership when it has something to share, but apart from that just stay out of the way.

If threads aren't the way to go here, what then? `fork`ing and proper IPC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that Perl variables are not shared by default, which combines with a bit of weirdness about which thread is servicing which signal to produce the result you're seeing.

When you spawn your hunting threads, each of them gets its own copy of `@dogs` and its contents.  That's just the way Perl threads work: the interpreter and its current state -- `@dogs`, `%SIG`, the open `STDOUT` -- is cloned entire.  To see how that works, consider this code:

```
my %dog_decls = (
    Labrador    => 1,
    Retriever   => 2,
    Shepherd    => 3,
);

while (my ($name, $delay) = each %dog_decls) {
    my $dog = Dog->new($name, $delay);
    push @dogs, $dog;
    threads->create(sub { $dog->hunt });
}

$_->join for threads->list;
```

The cloning happens at `threads->create` time, so each of these threads is getting a different version of `@dogs` to take with it.  As a consequence, the list of `Dogs` that bark when one of them catches a duck depends on which thread catches the signal!  (Also note that you can infer the order in which `each` happened to emit the hash from this output.)

> Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Labrador: found 1 ducks!
>
> Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Labrador: found 2 ducks!
>
> Retriever: found 1 ducks!
>
> Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Labrador: found 3 ducks!
>
> Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Labrador: found 4 ducks!
>
> Retriever: found 0 ducks!, Labrador: found 0 ducks!, Shepherd: found 1 ducks!

Back to your code:  When the `Labrador` thread (thread 1) wakes up, it updates the `Labrador`'s `ducksfound` and sends a `SIGUSR1`.  Someone (and we'll talk more about who in a second) sees the signal and `barks` all the `Dogs`.  But the only `Labrador` that's been changed is the one in thread 1.  The `Retriever` and `Shepherd` threads (threads 2 and 3 respectively) have not seen the update to `Labrador`'s `ducksfound`.

Why then is the value for `ducksfound` printed correctly at first?  Because of the way you installed the signal handler.  You installed it process-wide -- recall that I said `%SIG` was among the things cloned to your threads.  So each of the threads has a handler for `USR1` that causes all the `Dogs` to `bark`.  When you send `USR1` to `$$`, whichever thread happens to be awake at that moment catches it.  And it so happens that the thread that sent the signal is the thread that is awake.

And that explains why when the `Retriever` catches its first duck, its `ducksfound` value is correct but the `Labrador`'s is not.  `Retriever` catches the duck in thread 2, which sends `SIGUSR1` to itself and then `barks` all its `Dogs`.  But in thread 2, the `Labrador` has never been updated, and so the bark shows 0 for `Labrador` and 1 for `Retriever`.

The problem of unshared variables can be gotten around fairly simply by use of `threads::shared`:

```
use threads::shared;
...
my @dogs :shared;
...
push @dogs, shared_clone(Dog->new("Labrador",  1));
```

Now when one thread updates a `Dog`, all threads will see it and so it doesn't matter which thread is servicing the signal.  Which is good, because in your code the "main thread" (thread 0) never gets back control.  This might be okay, but probably leads to slightly weirder behavior than you expect.

If you actually want there to exist a manager thread, you probably need to spawn it explicitly:

```
# in Dog::new
        my ($class, $name, $hunter, $dt) = @_;
        ...
        hunter => $hunter,
# in Dog::hunt
        $self->{hunter}->kill('USR1');
# in main
my $hunter_thread = threads->create(
    sub {
        local $SIG{USR1} = sub {
            say join ", ", map { $_->bark } @dogs;
        };
        while (1) { usleep 100_000 } # higher resolution than hunt events
    }
);
...
push @dogs, shared_clone(Dog->new("Labrador", $hunter_thread, 1));
```

Note that just putting in a manager thread without sharing your `Dogs` would result in a thread that wakes up to print a bunch of zeroes.  You need to do both to get the results you were expecting.

Comment: > When you spawn your hunting threads, each of them gets its own copy of @dogs and its contents.

What I intended was for

    `push @dogs, Dog->new("Labrador", 1);`

to spawn an instance of some `Dog` and save a reference in the hunter (thread zero). How come the `Dog`'s know about `@dogs`?

Normally I would just sit down and do as I'm told, but seeing as I'm trying to learn this stuff, I figure it's alright to be a bit dense... :)

Comment: The way Perl threads work, the interpreter entire is cloned along with its current state.  You do indeed create `@dogs` in thread 0.  Then the `threads->create` calls clone all of the current state -- including `@dogs` and `%SIG` -- into the new threads.  I believe these are COW copies and so not terribly heavy, but this behavior is why tutorials on Perl threads advise you to spawn before loading too many modules or doing too much work in thread 0.

Comment: @K-spacer Added an example about that to the answer.

Comment: The penny just dropped so hard, my neighbour woke up and started banging on the wall... the **whole** damn thing is copied, thread zero included, so I effectively have 3 managers running, fighting for control of stdout, each with their private pack of dogs. I got it! Thank you so much, sir, you went A and B the C of D on this one!

Comment: This is a fantastic and very thorough answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation!